# sql statement select constraints

Tags: mysql

I have a table like the following

```
table_fruit:

account_id    fruit
1             apple
1             banana
2             apple
2             orange
2             banana
3             apple
```

I'm trying to make a list of everyone that has an apple and no other fruit

This seems like an easy idea but its passing me right now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `not exists` as

```
select * from table_fruit t1
where t1.fruit = 'apple'
and not exists(
  select 1 from table_fruit t2
  where t2.account_id = t1.account_id
  and t2.fruit <> 'apple'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Select * From table_fruit Where fruit = 'apple'
```

or
    Select * From table_fruit Where fruit like '%apple%'

Comment: This would grab everyone that has the fruit apple, I needed everyone that ONLY has an apple. Thanks for trying though.